# How to change a label's outlet from another view controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

So I was working with SmileLock library. I have problems changing a few texts and outlets when the view loads again after entering the correct password. This is the first Login page where you navigate to the password entry VC. I have tried and made my issue clear through the comments in my code.

```
import UIKit

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    //Made this to access this VC from other VCs.
    static var instance = LoginVC()

    //A button which is activated if the password is correct and goes to the next page.
    @IBOutlet weak var enterMainPage: UIButton!

    //A label which I'd want to change its text.
    @IBOutlet weak var statusSection: UILabel!

    //MARK: Property
    let isBlurUI = true

    var loginVCID: String!
    var mainTBCID: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("correct 8")

        //The button is inactive in every load.
        enterMainPage.isEnabled = false
        PASSWORD_IS_CORRECT: Bool = false

        //This loads up the password entry page when the login button is pressed.
        loginVCID = isBlurUI ? "BlrPasswordLoginVC" : "PasswordLoginVC"
    }


    @IBAction func enterMainPagePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

    @IBAction func presentLoginVC(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        PASSWORD_IS_CORRECT = true
        print("correct 10")
        present(loginVCID)

        //This was the only way I was not getting any errors (Unexpectedly found nil).
        self.loadView()
    }


    func present(_ id: String) {
        let mainVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id)
        mainVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        present(mainVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

This is the password entry page where I tried to change the text of my label directly but ended up with "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping" error. I'll point it out in the code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //create PasswordUIValidation subclass
        passwordUIValidation = MyPasswordUIValidation(in: passwordStackView)

        passwordUIValidation.success = { [weak self] _ in
            print("*️⃣ success!")
            PASSWORD_IS_CORRECT = true
            if PASSWORD_IS_CORRECT {
                //This is where I got the unexpected unwrapping error.
                LoginVC.instance.statusSection.text = "sample text"
                print("password is correct")
            }
```

All I need is to be able to change the label's text and a few other changes. Feel free to change whenever you felt necessary.

Comment: you should pass an object to your LoginVC with delegate pattern to let him know that password was correct or wrong, and in LoginVC you should handle that event

Comment: @ReinierMelian is it possible for you to put a little hand into this? A simple code line would suffice, thank you.

Comment: OK I will post an answer for you

Comment: @ReinierMelian thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Notification` or `delegate`

> Notification

```
extension Notification.Name {    
    static let passwordNotification = Notification.Name(
        rawValue: "password_Notification")
}

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
       notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                               selector: #selector(LoginVC.getPassword),
                               name: .passwordNotification,
                               object: nil)
    }

  @objc func getPassword(_ notification:NSNotification){
        if  let password =  notification.object as? String {
            self.statusSection.text =  password
        }
      }
}
```

in your password Controller

Remove this  `LoginVC.instance.statusSection.text = "sample text"`

and add this

```
 let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
                        notificationCenter.post(name: .passwordNotification, object: "sample text")
```

Comment: @ciklukylok please click on the checkmark next to this answer if this solved your problem